# Php array striping out html

Tags: php

If I dont use the implode my html tags dont show. Why? What should I use in an array so this does not incur?

```
if( get_field('additional_specifications') ) {
    while ( have_rows('additional_specifications') ) : the_row();
    $addSpec[] = '<tr><td>' . get_sub_field('spec_name') . '</td><td>' . get_sub_field('spec_value') . '</td></tr>'; 

endwhile;
    $spec= implode($addSpec);

$content .=  $spec; 
}

if ($content) {
echo '<table class="spec-table">',$content,'</table>';
}
```

Comment: can't you just replace `$addSpec[] = ` with `$content .=  `

Comment: if ($content) {
echo '<table class="spec-table">',$content,'</table>';
} it error sytax, must be echo '<table class="spec-table">' . $content . '</table>';

Comment: @buivankim2020 actually [commas work fine](http://www.tehplayground.com/#csy5IRThU)

Comment: commas work but "." is better syntax probably. @Memor-X $content .= works great thanks. I wonder why someone down voted me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( get_field('additional_specifications') ) {
    while ( have_rows('additional_specifications') ) : the_row();
        $content .= '<tr><td>' . get_sub_field('spec_name') . '</td><td>' . get_sub_field('spec_value') . '</td></tr>'; 
endwhile;

}

if ($content) {
    echo '<table class="spec-table">'. $content .'</table>';
 }
 ?>
```